# How should I style this img element to achieve the effect I want

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, styled-components

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-margulis-rr9zo

Guys this is the code I have so far. Pretend the chrome logo is the photo of a person. [image]

I need the photo to be side by side of the name and subtitle. And when you narrow your browser, the logo will get closer to the text and the logo will be under the text. I used `styled-component` and the style I wrote for the logo are

```
const ImgCotainer = styled.img`
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  z-index: -1;
`;
```

However, what I achieved so far has two major problems.

First is, I am not really good at CSS. I cannot really position the logo well(as you can see in the demo)

Second, I set the `z-index: -1;` to make it below the text. But weirdly it takes roughly 1 sec to make that overlap happen. You will get what I mean when you see the demo.

I know my question might be trivial to someone who have lots of experience with css but I really appreciate any help.

Finally, the look I aim to achieve is something like this. I feel like the photo is more likely to be a stand alone `img` rather than the background-image of the whole thing. And I tried to find the source code for websites like this and learn how they did it and the animation related to it but I just couldn't find it.  [image]

Comment: I would do 2 things: 1. Put the image in a div with the name and subtitle so that they’ll be positioned together. 2. Create a media query that will hide the image a show a background image based on the screen width.

Comment: @Rom Hi thank you for your prompt reply. And yes they are in the same container(`<TransitionGroup>`) even though it is not exactly a `div`.

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question **in the question itself**, please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can set width of the image to change with respect to viewport width and also set the desired max-width of the image for larger screens.

Set display to block and left and right margin to auto to display your image in the center horizontally.

```
const ImgCotainer = styled.img`
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;
```

Here is a sample image you can use.

```
const img = () => (
    <div style={{ transitionDelay: "600ms"}}>
      <ImgCotainer src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/doctor/doctor_PNG16036.png" />
    </div>
);
```

**Solution 2:**

Setting positioning and z-index to the image container's parent element will solve your problem of image animating in front of the text and then animating under the text after a few seconds.

```
const img = () => (
    <div style={{ 
      transitionDelay: "600ms",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      display: "flex",
      zIndex: -1,
      justifyContent: "center" 
    }}>
      <ImgCotainer src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/doctor/doctor_PNG16036.png" />
    </div>
 );
```

In this case your image container can be very simple.

```
const ImgCotainer = styled.img`
   width: 80vw;
   max-width:  700px;
`;
```

Check the following implementation:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-platform-ih3ki?fontsize=14)

[Demo](https://ih3ki.csb.app/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed solutions! I really appreciate it! I do have two questions I'd like to ask: 1. I tried to view the demo of yours using Phone device option and it is under the text which is great, however there is some margin(or blank content) that occupies the space on the right of the screen, which means you can try move the screen to the left and you see there is a blank area on the right side. I wanted to make the page always fit the width of the screen exactly so that you cannot move the screen horizontally. How can I modify the code to fix this?

Comment: also could you explain to me why was it that in my original demo, the logo went under the text **after** several seconds which is really weird to me.

Comment: In your original demo, the logo went under the text after several seconds (3s) was because in your CSSTransition loop, you have applied "fadeup" transition on parent div element (the img variable), without defining it's position and z-index. On the other hand, defining position and z-index for the child "ImgCotainer" component never make sense, since no css transition was directly being applied to it. The child container's z-index comes into effect after the entire animation sequence of **3000ms timeout** is completed, until then React CSS Transistion will be in control of your child elements.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the blank space using the phone device option on my browser, if you can help me with the steps to reproduce it, that will help. Also, in your layout component, there's an extra **)** at the end of this link **<div className="container">{children}</div>**, which renders in your final html output as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to achieve it.

1- Wrap your whole elements (6 elements 1 to 5 + img) with styled Component, let's name it  `Flex` .

2- Your first 5 elements should be wrapped in a div so that the 5 elements themselves will appear vertically but the whole div will aligned horizontally with img div.

3- wrap your image with other div

Now they will align horizontally next to each other. For mobile devices, you should add media query in `Flex` component to change the direction:

Your `Flex` Component will be like:

```
const Flex = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; // To align the image in the center with the text.
  div:nth-child(1) {
    margin: 20px; // to have some spaces between the text and the image
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
`;
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hawking-7tl8n)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer! It works great but the fade-in animation of the text disappears somehow